# Writing metadata to AVURLAsset?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm currently writing an app that uses an AVMediaPlayer to play AVURLAsset representations of downloaded mp3 files. The GUI is heavily based on the files' metadata as opposed to their file names. I don't have a problem accessing preexisting metadata information (for that I just use the metadataForFormat: method of AVURLAsset), but I'd like to write new metadata to untagged/incorrectly tagged files. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have you had a look at the [AVMetaDataItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVMetadataItem) class? According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188), this is used to set Metadata for AVAssets.

Comment: Yes I scoured the entire AVFoundation documentation for nearly 2 hours last night, including the documentation for `AVMutableMetaDataItem` and `AVMetaDataItem`. I've worked with these classes when reading existing metadata, but can't figure out how to write these objects to an AVAsset...

Comment: Not even the `commonMetadata` property of AVAsset?

Comment: Is that a writeable property? *facepalm*

Comment: Ah, no. It's readonly. A harder problem than it first looked. Have you tried the Developer forums, on the Cocoa-Dev mailing list? They are usually good sources for particularly gritty questions such as this.

Comment: How would I go about asking my question on the developer forums? Can you post a link to it?

Comment: [devforums](http://devforums.apple.com) and [Cocoa-Dev](http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/cocoa-dev)